# Rust: borrow struct instance as mutable multiple times fails, even though scopes are used

Tags: struct, rust, mutable, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am trying to create a **struct**, which contains a hashmap and a vector, thereby the **vector** should contain **references to values** from the **hashmap**.

I thought that multiple mutable borrows on the same instance are possible, when put into independent [scopes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/references-and-borrowing.html#thinking-in-scopes).

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95bfceb09c0c53b2d87f7ac2a1156e1c))

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Container<'a> {
    map: HashMap<String, String>,
    vec: Vec<&'a String>
}

impl<'a> Container<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Container {
            map: HashMap::new(),
            vec: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add_link(&'a mut self, key: &str) {
        if let Some(value) = self.map.get(key) {
            self.vec.push(value);
        }
    }

    pub fn print_vec(&self) {
        println!("Vec: {:?}", self.vec);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container::new();

    {
        container.map.insert("a".to_string(), "x".to_string());
    }
    {
        container.map.insert("b".to_string(), "y".to_string());
    }
    {
        container.map.insert("c".to_string(), "z".to_string());
    }

    {
        container.add_link("c");
    }
    {
        container.add_link("a");
    }
    {
        container.add_link("c");
    }
    {
        container.add_link("k");
    }

    container.print_vec();
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `container` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:44:9
   |
41 |         container.add_link("c");
   |         --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
44 |         container.add_link("a");
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here
   |         first borrow later used here


(...)
```

I am expecting the output to be: `Vec: ["z", "x", "z"]`

Comment: I am reading this answer but I don't quite understand what I have to change in my code to make it work.

Comment: There's no easy answer. What you're trying to do is not a simple problem (for example, what happens if the `HashMap` has to reallocate? As written, this would invalidate all the references in the vector, which is not good). Read the answers at the linked question very closely and then make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

**It is not** *(yet 1.41.1)* **trivial to implement self referencing structs.**

Like @SCappella mentioned, there is already a more detailed approach to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/9135945).

---

My approach to solve the problem is to bypass the original problem with splitting my container struct up in two separate structs, where the referencing struct is apart from the data-owning struct.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f04b8ad4ecde6b7b579768e76fced0c4))

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Container {
    map: HashMap<String, String>,
}

struct DependentContainer<'a> {
    vec: Vec<&'a String>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Container {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, key: &str, value: &str) {
        self.map.insert(key.to_string(), value.to_string());
    }
}

impl<'a> DependentContainer<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DependentContainer {
            vec: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add_link(&mut self, container: &'a Container, key: &str) {
        if let Some(value)= container.map.get(key) {
            self.vec.push(value);
        }
    }

    pub fn print_vec(&self) {
        println!("Vec: {:?}", self.vec);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container::new();
    let mut dep_container = DependentContainer::new();

    container.add("a", "x");
    container.add("b", "y");
    container.add("c", "z");

    dep_container.add_link(&container, "c");
    dep_container.add_link(&container, "a");
    dep_container.add_link(&container, "c");
    dep_container.add_link(&container, "k");

    dep_container.print_vec();
}
```